# Pass a class object in a java method dynamically

Tags: java, class

I have two methods which are very similar in implementation except that it accepts two different class objects. I want to try and refactor the code so that I can have one method in which I can pass different class objects.

```
public class Service{
     
     public void process(){
      ...
      payload = ModifyRequest(name, body, transformed);
        }  
     public String ModifyRequest(String name, JsonNode body, Mda transformed){ 
       Data data = new data;
       data = objectMapper.readValue(cardDetail, Data.class);
       Set<Mda> mdas = data.getMdas() 
       ......
       }
     }
```

Now I would like to use the same method ModifyRequest with a different object of different class. How can I do it with Java?

I want something like this if possible

```
public String ModifyRequest(String name, JsonNode body, Dam transformed)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Data data = new data;` is not valid Java, and for it to immediately be followed by  `data = objectMapper.readValue(cardDetail, Data.class);` doesn't make sense.  Can you post 'real' code (redacted to make your point, but at least valid Java syntax).

Comment: Please show the code to be reused or refactored - I do not understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to have 2 implementations of `modifyRequest` with different signatures? That is already possible. What is the difference between them? What do they share beyond the name?

Answer (score 0):

Use some oop concepts inheritance, interfaces, etc.

Update, if wanted superclass not be aware from subclasses, fine also (see `getMyMethod` and there add the behavior)

Eg:

```
public class Test01 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test01 t = new Test01();
        //MyObject o = t.new MyObject();
        Person p = t.new Person("NoName");
        Animal a = t.new Animal("meat",33.3);
        MyObject o = p;
    
        System.out.println(o.getType(p));
        System.out.println(o.call(p));
        System.out.println(o.getMyMethod(p));
        System.out.println(o.getMyMethod(a));
        
        o = a;
        System.out.println(o.getType(a));
        System.out.println(o.call(a));
        System.out.println(o.getMyMethod(a));
        System.out.println(o.getMyMethod(p));
        
        System.out.println(t.getMyMethod(p));
        System.out.println(t.getMyMethod(a));
        System.out.println(t.getMyMethod(1));
        System.out.println(t.getMyMethod(new Object()));
        
    }
    public String getMyMethod(Object o)
    {
        //handle logic based on type
        if(o instanceof Animal)
        {
            return "type is Animal";
        }
        else if(o instanceof Person)
        {
            return "type is Person";
        }
        else if(o instanceof Integer)
        {
            return "type is Integer";
        }
        else
            return "unknown type";
    }
    abstract class MyObject
    {   
        public String call(Object o)
        {
            return o.toString();
        }
        
        public String getType(Object o)
        {
            //do whatever wanted with a particular instance-type
            if(o instanceof Person)
                return "Person";
            else if(o instanceof Animal)
                return "Animal";
            else return "other type";
        }
        
        public abstract String getMyMethod(MyObject o);
    }
    class Person extends MyObject
    {
        String name;
        Person(String name)
        {
            this.name=name;
        }
        public Person getPerson()
        {
            return this;
        }
        
        public String toString()
        {
            return "My name is " + name;
        }
        
        public  String getMyMethod(MyObject o)
        {
            return "call from Person:"+o;
        }
    }
    
    class Animal extends MyObject
    {
        String meal;
        double weight;
        Animal(String meal, double weight)
        {
            this.meal = meal;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
        public Animal getAnimal()
        {
            return this;
        }
        
        public String toString()
        {
            return "I have "+weight+" kg because I eat "+meal;
        }
        
        public  String getMyMethod(MyObject o)
        {
            if(o instanceof Animal)
            {
                return "call from Animal:"+o;
            }
            
            return "call from Animal: hey this is only for Animals";
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Person
My name is NoName
call from Person:My name is NoName
call from Person:I have 33.3 kg because I eat meat

Animal
I have 33.3 kg because I eat meat
call from Animal:I have 33.3 kg because I eat meat
call from Animal: hey this is only for Animals

type is Person
type is Animal
type is Integer
unknown type
```

Now, for your purpose maybe the easiest way is just to write the method with a parament that accepts various types (even Object or refine) and based on type do the logic.

Last example `public String getMyMethod(Object o)`

Comment: That does not look very OO to me. Superclasses should not be aware of their subclasses